# Compatibility Test and other testing method to use while building software

Tags: unit-testing, testing, open-source, compatibility

I will be adding a feature to the software and have to update or modify some of public API of the present open source software.

What are steps which could be taken to ensure the compatibility of the software. what are the testing methods which are used in open source world to test the newly added features?? Open Source program is: Xapian

Comment: What do you mean under "compatibility test"? To ensure it runs on different platforms/hardware ?

Comment: compatibility test here when i update an API of opensource software.what measures must be taken to see that changes doesn't affect the previous functionality of that API with new changes.
What must be kept in mind while development to avoid any chances of API old functionality breaking.

Comment: Hey, you can consider following measures during testing (regression testing) – 
[1]. Rerun test cases for modified module 
[2]. Achieve adequate confidence in software quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a new feature is added in existing software you need to test software by applying regression testing. You can also follow this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing)

Comment: Yes, I also think regression testing is best option.Majorly the open source software maintain the API test to check if the functionality are working fine.
Hence running all API test must be first intital step towards ensuring compatibility...
Are there any other????

Comment: then, you can try Maintenance testing..